# Magento only parent category id

Tags: magento, categories

Hello i need only top level categories id that is i need only parent category id not the subcategories. such as :

Root Category (No Need of its ID)

1. Furniture (only this id)
   a. living room (not this subcategories)
   b. Bedroom (not this one)

I need Only top level categories id not the children Please help me doing so Thanks

Comment: Hello Guys thanks for the help but here i need one more thing if i am in living room category page & i want to display both the sub categories of its parents subcategories that is living room & bedroom . How can i do that please .

Comment: pretty simple   use In your filter and get both level 2 and Level 4 categories , when you're in level 3 category page ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array("in"=>array('2','4'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF am not wrong you are looking only for LEVEL 2 category Ids. If so the code below helps you

```
   $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('level','2')
                 ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                 ->addIsActiveFilter();
        foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
            echo '<br/>'.$cat->getId().' | '.$cat->getName();
        }
```

To Get both Level 2 and Leve 4 catgories just use 'in' operator to filer your collection as shown below :

```
   $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array('in'=>('2','4')))
                 ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                 ->addIsActiveFilter();
        foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
            echo '<br/>'.$cat->getId().' | '.$cat->getName();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man thank u very much it works & get me all level 2 categories thanks

Comment: @rishu You are welcome. BTW find my updated answer above for your latest comment to filter both level 2 and level 4 categories

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
foreach ($children as $category) {
    echo $category->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
$_categories=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
                ->addIsActiveFilter();
```